# Click all but one element in a container to link

Tags: javascript, jquery

So in...

```
<div id="a">
     <img src="/foo/bar.jpg">
</div>
```

I want to be able to click everywhere inside of the div EXCEPT for on the image...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      // Somehow select id A but not the image here?!
      $("#a").click(function(){
           window.location = 'http://google.com';
      });
 });
```

Is this possible?

I tried using .not() and :not(), but could not figure it out...Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [`jQuery.is` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/is/). You can check which element was clicked from the `event.target`

```
$("#a").click(function(e){
    if(!$(e.target).is('img'))
       window.location = 'http://google.com';
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gkDLg/)

Comment: Thanks for the help! Love fiddle by the way...I hadn't ever seen that before!

Comment: @jcreamer898 - welcome! glad to help. Fiddle is great; it can be very useful for asking questions too.

Answer (score 1):

Events are triggered on all parent elements of the element where it originated.  You need to check which element triggered the event:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#a").click(function(e){
        if (e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() !== 'img') {
            window.location = 'http://google.com';
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @patrick - although this example is functionally equivalent `is` allows for a more complicated check than `nodeName` (multiple images, class names, etc)

Comment: @Josiah True, but in is case it is *far* slower.

Comment: @lonesomeday: Far slower? Sounds like premature optimization to me. This is response to user event, not a tight loop. I prefer clean code over over-optimization. `is` allows you to modify the HTML structure while minimizing code changes.

Comment: @Josiah: That's true. I just prefer to avoid overhead of using sophisticated tools until I need them. Just my preference.

Comment: @Juan Mendez: I'm curious that you phrased *"Far slower"* as a question. So far testing in Chrome, there's a greater than 30x difference. http://jsperf.com/jquery-is-vs-node-name-tolowercase

Comment: Sure, 30x faster. The point is: does that make a difference? Unless it's a critical loop, it does not. At 150,000 ops per second, that's less than 1/100 of a millisecond. I always prefer to use abstractions instead of getting dirty (unless performance is truly affected)... Mende**s** by the way!

Comment: @Juan: Yes I understand that. Just a difference in preference. I prefer to be in the habit if coding toward optimization when convenient. And I consider this to be convenient. Of course we could avoid the issue altogether if we just give the `img` its own handler by chaining `.find('img').bind('click',false);`.

Comment: @patrick: I must agree that I went a bit overboard, this is not even close to what I would call over-optimization... My guess is you've had as many problems with performance as I have had with trying to refactor over-optimized code. It is definitely a difference in preference and I'm sure in we would agree in favor of performance if this was a tight loop, or for abstraction if this code had lots of browser specific code (or something like it)

Comment: @Juan Mendes: Yes, I think that preferences aside we're overall in agreement. And my apologies for the "z" mixup. That was sloppy of me. You'd be amazed at what my brain sees in spite of my eyes.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<div style="position:relative;width:100px;height:100px">
    <a style="display:block;width:100px;height:100px;position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px" href="http://google.de">Google</a>
    <img src="/foo/bar.png" style="position:absolute;top:10px;left:10px" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to look at [event.target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) Wrote an example here at [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/otiga3/edit)